# ¿como consultar rentas mayores a 30 con tabla derivada en sakila mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, join

Estoy utilizando la base de datos sakila y ocupo realizar una consulta donde aparezca el cliente,peliculas en donde las rentas sean mayores a 30(Numero de rentas por pelicula mayores a 30),nombre de la pelicula(que sean mayores a 30)
No logro relacionar correctamente el numero de las rentas con la pelicula,esto es lo que llevo
Hasta el momento logro que de el nombre del cliente,nombre de la pelicula,categoria pero falta que el numero de rentas para que solo aparezcan aquellas peliculas que tengan mayor a 30

```
    select concat(first_name," ",last_name) as nombre,f.title as Pelicula,cat.name as categoria
    from customer c
left join rental rt on c.customer_id=rt.customer_id
left join inventory i on rt.inventory_id=i.inventory_id
left join film f on i.film_id=f.film_id
left join film_category fc on f.film_id=fc.film_id
left join category cat on cat.category_id=fc.category_id
INNER JOIN (
select i.film_id idpelicula,count(r.rental_id)rentas
from inventory i
inner join rental r on i.inventory_id=r.inventory_id
join customer cus on r.customer_id=cus.customer_id
where cus.customer_id=r.customer_id
group by i.film_id having rentas >30
) peliculas

group by nombre
order by rt.rental_id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, para encontrar el número de rentas de una misma película por un mismo cliente, puedes basarte en la tabla `rental` e `inventory`, sin relacionarla con cliente, por ejemplo:

```
select i.film_id, r.customer_id, count(r.rental_id) rentas
  from inventory i
       inner join rental r on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
 group by i.film_id, r.customer_id
having count(r.rental_id) > 30
```

Esta consulta es la que, entonces, debieras utilizar como tabla derivada para producir tu consulta final, en donde ya podrás relacionarla con la tabla de clientes y películas para obtener nombres y otra información que te interese, por ejemplo:

```
select   f.title
       , c.first_name
       , a.VecesRentada
  from (select i.film_id, r.customer_id, count(r.rental_id) VecesRentada
          from inventory i
               inner join rental r on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
         group by i.film_id, r.customer_id
        having count(r.rental_id) > 30
       ) a
       inner join film on film.film_id = a.film_id
       inner join customer c on c.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

En la consulta de ejemplo que pusiste, la tabla derivada tiene un where que *intenta* relacionarla con la tabla `customer` que está en un nivel superior. Esperaría que mySQL lanzara un error en este caso, pero si no lo hace (mal por él), de todas maneras me parece incorrecto. Una tabla derivada **no es** una sub-consulta, y no debiera tener acceso a datos que están en tablas declaradas fuera de la propia definición de la consulta misma que forma la tabla o parámetros. El resto de la relación, debiera construirse en la clausula `on` de los `joins` o en el `where` de la consulta *madre*.

---

Disclaimer: No conozco el esquema, pero con ver la consulta que has incluido creo haberlo comprendido, es buena idea siempre incluir las partes relevantes del esquema como parte de la pregunta.